# Which Is the Best one LInq Or Ado.Net For Retrieving Data From Database Using Multiple Joins?

Tags: linq, ado.net

I need information for Which is the best for the retrieve data from the database using bundle joins.

Comment: It's impossible to answer such a vague question. LINQ itself doesn't query databases, it's a language used by **ORMs**. It's the *ORM* that generates JOINs from the relations between *entities*. You shouldn't be writing joins at all if you use LINQ on top of EF or NHibernate

Comment: In the end, the *ORMs* generate SQL queries that get executed using ADO.NET

Comment: I will only consider linq(in terms of entity framework which is an orm) and other orm's due to its readability but when it comes to the performance of complex queries i will definitely go for the stored procedures and calling the procedure using the orm.
Ado .net is good too but the only problem with that is code readability